# Firebase database in unity platform android unsubscribe doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

The version that I am using is:

Firebase version 5.4.2 and 5.5.0
Unity version 2018.5.5f1

I am using childAdded to registering or unsubscribing are normal on the editor,
but I am not able to unsubscribe after building apk,
It receives the same return event as the number of subscriptions each time the data is added.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar error. I had these two functions that were working fine in unity editor but didn't work on an Android device using APK.

```
private void OnEnable ()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/currentGame").ValueChanged += HandleComingGameChanges;
}

private void OnDisable ()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/currentGame").ValueChanged -= HandleComingGameChanges;
}
```

So i just added a DatabaseReference variable and subscribe to that OnEnable function and unsubscribe to that on GameObject-Disable function and it starts working.

Here is the pseudo code of this.

```
private DatabaseReference reference;
private void Awake ()
{
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/myReference");
}
private void OnEnable ()
{
    reference.ValueChanged += HandleChanges;
}

private void OnDisable ()
{
    reference.ValueChanged -= HandleChanges;
}
```

Note: I'm initializing reference variable in Awake function because it is called before OnEnable and Start is called after OnEnable.

Comment: but when I add filter like OrderByChild("xyz") , it cannot unsubscribe. 
Do you have any workaround ?
Thanks

Comment: @user3804063 can you please share your code snippet.